Vue i18n VS Code Snippet
Is there a way to easily add an i18n string to a .vue file?

Not really a Nuxt/Vue question but I guess you want this as a reminder for yourself. Even tho there is probably such a question on this platform elsewhere.

Ok, here's how I figured it out:

Go into the project folder and create a .vscode folder (if it doesn't exist) then create a snippet file inside the .vscode folder like this: i18n-snippet.code-snippets.
Add the following code to the snippet file:

{
    "i18n": {
        "prefix": "i18n",
        "body": [
            "{{ \\$t('$1') }}"
        ],
        "description": "Create an i18n snippet"
    }
    
}



You can now easily create an i18n template tag in your vue file. Just type i18n (or just i1) in your vue file

